# Populate Rotatable Access Logs From Sample File in Linux

Tags: shell, awk, getline

I am trying to generate near real time access logs from a sample access log file.
For the sake of simplicity, I want to generate 2 events per 2 seconds.
below is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sample_log_file=$1
populated_log_file=$2

#create new access log file if not existing
if [[ ! -e ./$populated_log_file ]]
then
    touch $populated_log_file
fi

while true
do
        echo "reading sample file"
        #get size of the new access log file in bytes
        populated_log_bytes=$(stat -c%s "./$populated_log_file");
        
        # pass count =2 -> how many events to generate per 2 seconds
        # pass name of the new access log file
        # pass size of the new access log file, to be incremented whenever a new log is populated below

        awk -v count=2 -v plf=$populated_log_file -v plb=$populated_log_bytes '
        {
            print "start batch of 2 events"
            for (j=1; j<=count; j++)
            {
                print j;
                k = $0;
                print k;
                #check generated file size, if >= 50 bytes, overwrite  it.
                if ( plb >= 50 )
                {
                    close(plf);
                    print k > plf ;
                    plb=length(k);
                }
                # else, if it is < 50 bytes , append to the generated log file
                else
                {
                    print k >> plf ;
                    plb += length($0)
                }
                getline;
            }
            system("sleep 2");
        }' $sample_log_file
done
```

Below is the sample file

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

And below is the generated output file:

```
line1
line2
line4
line5
```

Below is the output after debugging

```
reading sample file
start batch of 2 events
1
line1
2
line2
start batch of 2 events
1
line4
2
line5
```

So my question is, why the event(line3) is skipped and how to fix that.

Comment: awk reads one line by itself. you call `getline;` and read `line3`, then you exit loop, then `awk` reads `line4`, then you output it.

Comment: If you want `to generate near real time access logs from a sample access log file` then why process 2 events every 2 seconds instead of processing **all** new events once per second? I assume your input file is being written to by some other process while your script is being written. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/629909/133219 for inspiration.

Comment: @KamilCuk Any idea how to avoid this behavior.
I have already tried to add the following condition before the getline if (j+1 <= count)
but i got the following output
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line5

Comment: `if (j != count) getline;`...

Comment: @EdMorton well, the sample log file is originally generated in another productionized environment.
And i am practicing on a offline environment, so i take sample from the productionized environment log file, and try to generate near real time log from it. I will definitely need to read more events per second, but this was for the sake of simplicity. Thanks.

Comment: @KamilCuk
i got line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line5 (separated by new lines). i realized for the last batch, that when the awk go to the next line (line5), then the for loop j=1 != count, getline is executed, so the question here, why it still outputiing line5, as it should find the EOF, so it should stop and exit the for loop, then awk will exit as well!

Comment: because you do not check if getline is successfull. Maybe take a piece of paper and try to walk through your code _line by line_? `if (getline <= 0) print("Och nuu, end of input")` `as it should find the EOF, so it should stop and exit the for loop,` no, your loop stops when `j<=count` not at EOF, it's in your code, it's unrelated to end of input..

Comment: A few things aren't clear to me: a) what you mean by `try to generate near real time log from it.` when the input is a static file, b) why you're restricting how many events are processed at a time to a specific number instead of just processing all of them, c) why you're both using awks natural read loop and getline at the same time, and d) why you're using getline at all (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).

Comment: Your shell loop will call awk in iteration 1 which will run until it reaches the end of your input file then exit, so then your shell loop will call awk in iteration 2 which will start again at the start of your input file and again run until it reaches the end of your input file then exit. i.e. the awk script will always process from the start of the input file til the end of it - I don't see how that could be useful.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for your feedback. However, my question was about the how not the why. The reason is that there are limitations in the environment i am currently working on, so this is why i am trying to simulate real time events in this environment.

Comment: It's much easier for us to help you if we understand the "why" though. Asking just about the "how" is the definition of an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which can easily lead to us helping you implement the wrong approach to whatever it is you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think this is probably what you're trying to do (processing 1 or 2 events every 2 seconds):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/sh
sample_log_file=$1
populated_log_file=$2

#create new access log file if not existing
if [ ! -e "./$populated_log_file" ]
then
    touch "$populated_log_file"
fi

while true
do

    echo "reading sample file" >&2

    #get size of the new access log file in bytes
    populated_log_bytes=$(stat -c%s "./$populated_log_file");

    # pass count =2 -> how many events to generate per 2 seconds
    # pass name of the new access log file
    # pass size of the new access log file, to be incremented whenever a new log is populated below

    awk -v count=2 -v plf="$populated_log_file" -v plb="$populated_log_bytes" '
        BEGIN {
            print "start batch of " count " events" > "/dev/stderr"
        }
        {
            print NR, $0 > "/dev/stderr"

            lgth = length($0)

            #check generated file size, if >= 50 bytes, overwrite  it.
            if ( plb >= 50 )
            {
                close(plf)
                print > plf
                plb = lgth
            }
            # else, if it is < 50 bytes , append to the generated log file
            else
            {
                print >> plf
                plb += lgth
            }
        }
        (NR % count) == 0 {
            system("sleep 2")
            print "start batch of " count " events" > "/dev/stderr"
        }
    '

done < "$sample_log_file"
```

and I think this is probably what you should really be doing instead (processing all present events every 2 seconds):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/sh
sample_log_file=$1
populated_log_file=$2

#create new access log file if not existing
if [ ! -e "./$populated_log_file" ]
then
    touch "$populated_log_file"
fi

while true
do

    echo "reading sample file" >&2

    #get size of the new access log file in bytes
    populated_log_bytes=$(stat -c%s "./$populated_log_file");

    # pass count =2 -> how many events to generate per 2 seconds
    # pass name of the new access log file
    # pass size of the new access log file, to be incremented whenever a new log is populated below

    awk -v plf="$populated_log_file" -v plb="$populated_log_bytes" '
        BEGIN {
            print "start batch of all events" > "/dev/stderr"
        }
        {
            print NR, $0 > "/dev/stderr"

            lgth = length($0)

            #check generated file size, if >= 50 bytes, overwrite  it.
            if ( plb >= 50 )
            {
                close(plf)
                print > plf
                plb = lgth
            }
            # else, if it is < 50 bytes , append to the generated log file
            else
            {
                print >> plf
                plb += lgth
            }
        }
    '

    sleep 2

done < "$sample_log_file"
```

In both cases the script will keep processing new events being added to the input file rather than starting at the beginning of the input file again every time awk is called.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix this as below:

```
..
sample_log_file_lines="$(wc -l < $sample_log_file )"
..
while true
do
 ..
        awk  -v slf_lines=$sample_log_file_lines '
        {
                ...
                #order matters of the following two ifs
                if (NR == slf_lines)
                    break
                if (j != count)
                    getline;
                
            }
            system("sleep 2");
        }' $sample_log_file
done
```

Comment: You seem to be putting bandaids on a fundamentally wrong approach.